# LIKE and filtering of records with MySQL does no change

Tags: mysql, filtering, where-clause

I have my SQL, but the WHERE clause is what i'm having a problem with, since filtering out records with operators doesn't seem to filter the records, but picks up records when they shouldn't be, I need this LIKE/REGEXP to pick up records then narrow it down by including records that is *true* to the `=` statements.

```
WHERE  rec.street_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.city REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.state REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.country REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.street_name LIKE 'united'
OR rec.city LIKE 'united'
OR rec.state LIKE 'united'
OR rec.country LIKE 'united'  
AND rec.ad_type = 1  
AND ( rec.num_rooms >= 15 AND rec.num_rooms IS NOT NULL )  
AND rec.visible_listing = 1
```

Nor this WHERE clause does filter out records:

```
WHERE  rec.street_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.city REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.state REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.country REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.street_name LIKE 'united'
OR rec.city LIKE 'united'
OR rec.state LIKE 'united'
OR rec.country LIKE 'united' 
AND ( rec.ad_type = 1  AND ( rec.num_rooms >= 15 AND rec.num_rooms IS NOT NULL)  AND rec.visible_listing = 1 )
```

Even changing `rec.num_rooms` / `rec.ad_type` to any number still doesn't change anything. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parens around the ORs

```
WHERE  (rec.street_name REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.city REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.state REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.country REGEXP '[[:<:]]united[[:>:]]'
OR rec.street_name LIKE 'united'
OR rec.city LIKE 'united'
OR rec.state LIKE 'united'
OR rec.country LIKE 'united' )

AND rec.ad_type = 1  
AND rec.num_rooms >= 15 
AND rec.num_rooms IS NOT NULL 
AND rec.visible_listing = 1
```